# running jenkins under different user

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to run Jenkins under a different user than "Jenkins" on my ubuntu server. I want to run it under "alihasan".
I followed [this guide](http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html) and it used to work, used for years but it does not seem to work anymore.
As soon as I change user and chown dirs, Jenkins service fails to start, with errors like this

```
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/identity.key.enc (Permission denied)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.write(InstanceIdentity.java:97)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.<init>(InstanceIdentity.java:66)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.<init>(InstanceIdentity.java:40)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.PageDecoratorImpl.<init>(PageDecoratorImpl.java:22)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.PageDecoratorImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$1384067.GUICE$T
RAMPOLINE(<generated>)
May 16 14:11:29 mark85 jenkins[455372]:         at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.PageDecoratorImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$1384067.apply(<
generated>)
```

I have followed different other guides and fixes found on the internet for the past 3-4 days, but nothing worked.
I don't have much knowledge about it, any sort of help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after editing *User* and *Environment* variable directly in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/jenkins.service`
Maybe there is a better way such as using *systemctl edit jenkins*, but first one is working fine right now, at least until jenkins gets updated again.

Posting it if someone else comes around the same issue.